# Copying a sheet with macros isn't propagating fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet that has a few scripts to do things like hide/unhide rows, clear cells, and propagate empty cells.  These all work on the original spreadsheet, but when I make a copy of the spreadshee they all work except the one that's supposed to propagate the empty cells.

If you were to copy/paste what's in C9:H16 in the Gardens tab and paste it into C17:H24 then as long as there's nothing in them already cells P13:P20 in the Calculations tab will be propagated by the script from cells O13:O20 and in turn these will show up also in cells J17:J24 in the Gardens tab.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EyxM4qqVKrAsm2KOFnK-2NrUl5Kp-Ki60eb50OZou84/edit?usp=sharing

However if you make a copy of the spreadsheet and then do the above cells P13:P20 don't get propagated and so cells J17:J24 in the Gardens tab remain empty.

I really don't know why this doesn't work for spreadsheet copies, can anyone help please?

This is the script that is failing to behave...I don't know how to give access permissions to the script, I'm sorry I tried looking it up but I cannot find a simple answer or they're very outdated.

```
function seedsaver() {  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Calculation");
  
var plot = sheet.getRange("P3:P69");
var planted = sheet.getRange("B3:B69").getValues();
var seedcross = sheet.getRange("O3:O69").getValues();
var seedsaved = plot.getValues();

for (var row=1; row<planted.length; ++row) {    
  if (planted[row][0] == "") {
    seedsaved[row][0] = "";
  }  
  else if (seedcross[row][0] != "" && seedsaved[row][0] == "") {
    seedsaved[row][0] = seedcross[row][0];
    };
  };
  plot.setValues(seedsaved);
};
```

Comment: That's because you've this `and(isblank($C17),isblank(Calculation!P13))` condition applied on  `J Column`  and when `copy-paste` the data on `C17: ...` on `Gardens` sheet this `isblank(Calculation!P13)` becomes empty in `Calculation` sheet , because there is  no formula to update those cells, it look `manual` entry fields.

Comment: But it's supposed to be like that.  The script is checking P13 in Calculation to see if there's anything in it or if it matches what's in O13, if not then it copies what's in O13 to P13 and keeps it there until C17 on the Gardens has nothing in it, then J column is to copy what's in P13 to J17 on the Gardens sheet.  As I said it works in the original spreadsheet but it doesn't work on a copy of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Which part of the script does that?, how script run?, please provide minimal reproducible code.

Comment: I can't see your script, when you share it with view rights, please edit your question and paste that code there, so that other can easily evaluate it.

Comment: As checked from your sheet, that `seedsaver` function has set to trigger on `onChange Installable Trigger`.

So when you copy the sheet, bound `script` copies along with it but not `Installable Trigger`  as user has to set it again after `authorizing` it. That's what causing what you're facing.

Comment: I thought that too but I had a popup at the start when I ran the scripts and I authorized it.

Comment: You authorize it, but it doesn't add a trigger with the project, if you're authorising it you should programmatically add trigger with project

Comment: Oh!  Yes I see now, I have a trigger for the seedsaver function in the original script but not for the copy.  Hmm, is there any way to make the script add the trigger automatically upon authorizing the other scripts instead of having to add it in manually?  Or will I need to make some special workaround like a button tied to the trigger labelled something like "Click Me Once" to create the trigger?

Comment: Yes, you can do it both way, either add a button in menu or add button through drawing and assign the script to it, but you've to keep in mind that everytime that function run new trigger will be added.

Comment: If you're the only one using the sheet or you can give edit access of calculation sheet to every user, you can add that function with OnEdit function and that way you don't have to add installable trigger

Comment: Well I'll be...it works!!!  Thank you for helping me with this, I had no idea it was as simple as just calling it in the onEdit function.